# How to mock a util function specific to a it block in jest ? Each it block needs the function to return different values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Trying to test a React component using jest. So I have single describe block that contains 3 it blocks. Consider I'm mocking a util function useIsCarCostly as true, but in the 3rd it block I wanted it to be false to test specific scenarios. How do we mock a function specific to a it block.

React component

```
import React from "react";
import { useIsCarDetailsEnabled } from "../../../utils/utils";

const CarSection = ({ car, dispatch }) => {
  const isCarDetailsEnabled = useIsCarDetailsEnabled();

  return isCarDetailsEnabled ? (
    <div>
      {car.isCarCostly() ? (
        <h2>Expensive Car</h2>
      ) : (
        <h2>Affordable Car</h2>
      )}
    </div>
  ) : null;
};

export default CarSection;
```

Utils

```
const useIsCarDetailsEnabled = () => {
  // Some business logic
  return true;
};

export { useIsCarDetailsEnabled };
```

Test file

```
import React from "react";
import CarSection from "../CarSection"; 
import Car from "../../types/Car";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "react-query";
import { useIsCarDetailsEnabled } from "../../utils/utils";
const queryClient = new QueryClient();

jest.mock("../../utils/utils", () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual("../../utils/utils"),
  useIsCarDetailsEnabled: jest.fn(() => false),
}));

describe('CarSection tests', () => {
  let dispatchMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    dispatchMock = jest.fn();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

  const renderComponent = () => {
    return render(
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <CarSection 
          car={new Car({ model: "Toyota", price: 30000 })}
          dispatch={dispatchMock}
        />
      </QueryClientProvider>
    );
  };

  it('Check if component renders correctly when car details are not enabled', () => {
    const { container } = renderComponent();
    expect(container.firstChild).toBeNull();
  });

  it('Check if expensive car label renders if car is costly', () => {
    // How to useIsCarDetailsEnabled as true here 
    jest.spyOn(Car.prototype, 'isCarCostly').mockReturnValue(true);
    const { queryAllByText } = renderComponent();
    const expensiveCarLabel = queryAllByText("Expensive Car");
    expect(expensiveCarLabel.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
  });
});
```

Comment: It's entirely unclear how whatever you're testing actually fits together, but one thing that would _immediately_ be more straightforward is passing a test double of a `Car` to `renderComponent` rather than spying on the prototype. Also partially mocking anything (in this case the "utils") is a bit of a smell.

Answer (score 0):

You can mock a module and then import the mocked method or object, which gives you a reference to the mock that can be updated on the fly.

```js
import { myFunction } from '~/myFile'

jest.mock(
  '~/myFile',
  () => ({ myFunction: jest.fn() })
)

describe('some behaviour', () => {
  it('uses one mock value', () => {
    myFunction.mockReturnValue('a')
    
    // test here
  })

  it('uses another mock value', () => {
    myFunction.mockReturnValue('b')
    
    // test here
  })
})
```